# Finding distinct records based on variable 1 within groups grouped by variable 2

Tags: sql

I am working with the dataset with number of variables. One of them is ID NUMBER which should be distinct but it is not. I need to remove duplicates. However to do this I need to follow a logic based on another variable i.e. RECORD TYPE. For this I need to identify whether the RECORD TYPE is the same within each group of duplicates. I tried to identify all duplicates first and then use over partition by to go over each group of duplicated id numbers and count distinct record types. Finally, I included 'where' clause to only include those with more than one distinct type per each group of duplicates. Having said that, this become too complex for me as I am only starting with SQL and can't figure out how to produce the output in the table 2 below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Input TABLE]

[image]

```
select *
from (
      select ID_NUMBER, RECORD_TYPE,
      count(distinct(RECORD_TYPE)) over (partition by (ID_NUMBER) distinct_type
            from(
                 select *
                 from TABLE
                 where ID_NUMBER in (
                      select ID_NUMBER
                      from TABLE
                      group by ID_NUMBER
                      having count(*) > 1))
where distinct_type no in ('0'))
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OCBnnUt_)):

```
select id, record_type, count(*)
from test
where id in (select id from test
             group by id
             having count(distinct record_type) > 1
            )
group by id, record_type
order by id, record_type;
```

It should work in most databases (as you didn't specify which one you use); the `sql` tag is related to *language*.